# AngularJS - single controller for ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="client in clients" ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
     <td ng-click="toggleExpand()">
        Expand
     </td>
     <!-- some html -->
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="isExpanded" ng-repeat-end>
     <!-- some html -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this JS:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ClientCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.isExpanded= false;
   $scope.toggleExpand = function(){
       $scope.isExpanded = !$scope.isExpanded;
   }
});
```

For each repeated element, I want the same instance of `ClientCtrl` to apply to both `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`, so that `isExpanded` can be toggled from inside of `ng-repeat-start` and be accessible via `ng-repeat-end`.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

I'm not looking for workarounds to make the toggle work, what I really want is to be able to share a scope across `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`, and the functionality of the toggle is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way do do it:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="client in clients" ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
     <td ng-click="vm.toggleExpand()">
        Expand
     </td>
     <!-- some html -->
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="vm.isExpanded" ng-repeat-end ng-controller="ClientEndCtrl">
     <!-- some html -->
  </tr>
</table>


angular.module('app').controller('ClientCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.vm = {
       isExpanded: false,
       toggleExpand: function(){
           $scope.vm.isExpanded = !$scope.vm.isExpanded;
       }
   }
}).controller('ClientEndCtrl', function($scope){
    // vm is a shared view model across ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end
    $scope.vm = $scope.$$prevSibling.vm;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You will need to use the `$index` of the item in order to be able to toggle each individually.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="client in clients" ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
     <td ng-click="toggleExpand($index)">
        Expand
     </td>
     <!-- some html -->
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="isExpanded($index)" ng-repeat-end>
     <!-- some html -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

And update the `toggleExpand` function accordingly.

Comment: The question is about a more broad issue of sharing scopes across ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. I edited the question to be more clear.